# How to filter by range OR "null" value? (I.e. combine NumberFilter range and BooleanFilter for null=True IntegerField)

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter, django-filters

I have a `Item` model with a numeric `number` field. This `number` field defaults to null.

```
# models.py
class Item(models.Model):
  number = models.IntegerField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to set-up filters that can return a queryset of `Items` where `number` is in range - which is straightforward enough:

```
# filters.py
class ItemFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
  min_num = django_filters.NumberFilter(method="min_num_filter")
  max_num = django_filters.NumberFilter(method="max_num_filter")

  class Meta:
    model = Item
    fields = ("min_num", "max_num", "incl_null")

  def min_num_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
    return queryset.filter(number__gte=value)

  def max_num_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
    return queryset.filter(number__lte=value)
```

**But what if I want to have an additional Boolean filter that can include `Items` that has `null` for `number` along with whatever `Items` matches the `min_num` and `max_num` range?**

So for example, a URL query in the form of `?min_num=1&max_num=10&incl_null=True` should return all `Items` where `number` is between `1` and `10` **OR** `number` is equal to `None`.

The following code does not work:

```
class ItemFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
  ...
  incl_null = django_filters.BooleanFilter(method="incl_null_filter")

  class Meta:
    model = Item
    fields = ("min_num", "max_num", "incl_null")

  // doesn't work
  class incl_null_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
    if value is True:
      return queryset | Item.objects.filter(number=None)
    if value is False:
      return queryset
```

**Edit:** I've tried the methods in the "[Filtering by empty values](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/tips.html#filtering-by-empty-values)" documentation but I think that's for `null` values exclusively - where I'm looking for a range match **OR** a `null` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the only solution I can think of is to pass the min range, max range, and is_null boolean into a single `char` field then convert it into the 3 individual filters for actioning.

So the query URL will look like `?master_num=1-10-1` for range `1 - 10` incl. `None` and `?master_num=1-10-0` for range `1 - 10` excl. `None`.

```
class ItemFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
  master_num = django_filters.CharFilter(method="master_num_filter")

  class Meta:
    model = Item
    fields = ("master_num")

  def master_num_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
    # array = [min, max, 1 or 0 for True and False]
    array = value.split("-")
    min = Q(year_published__gte=int(array[0]))
    max = Q(year_published__lte=int(array[1]))
    if array[2] == "1":
        incl_null = Q(year_published=None)
        return queryset.filter((min & max) | incl_null)
    else:
        return queryset.filter(min & max)
```

Would like to know if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
from django.db.models import Q

min_ = 0
max_ = 10

Item.objects.filter(Q(number__gte=min_, number__lte=max_) | Q(number__isnull=True))
```

Comment: This is queryset filtering, the question is about django-filter.